# Add .NetCoreApp into .NetStandard

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I want to add .NetCoreApp version = v1.0 into a .NetStandard version = v1.6
as reference.
But when I try to do this then below error showing. I google for last 1 hour but not get any solution and still searching for proper solution.

[image]

Hope will get any idea.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try netcoreapp1.1 instead of netcoreapp1.0

Comment: why would you want to import netcoreApp into net standard, you should do the oposite. netcoreApp is the framework you build in and netStandardLib are the libraries you add. (but this is only needed for a project you want to run). Libraries build in netStandard can be used by NETcoreApp

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

Think `.NET Standard` is an interface, while `.NET Core` is class/implementation.

New interface (your project) can extends only interfaces (`netstandard` libraries can reference only other `netstandard` libraries), classes can extend both (your `netcoreapp` project can reference both `netstandard` and `netcoreapp`).

But you can't create an interface (`netstandard` lib) which extends class (uses `netcoreapp` app).